# How was Flash able to reverse the colour of Reverse-Flash's costume?

Tags: character, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-flashpoint-paradox

In Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox, Flash had only Reverse-Flash's ring/costume. So after he gets back his power, he uses this costume and does some kind of vibration and reverses the colours of this costume to make it like his own. What was this power all about? And how does it work? How was he able to change the colour of the costume?

Comment: He made it out of pure speed force http://thearrowverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Screen-Shot-2015-12-02-at-12.20.39-PM-copy1.png That, or he's just vibrating enough to red-shift it in color. ***Speedforce, ain't gotta explain sh$#***

Comment: Maybe he took a page out of Silver Age Superman's book, and used Super-Sewing?

Comment: I'm guessing Barry altered the electromagnetic radiation that all colours give of, matched it to his colour choice and changed the colour scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to have taken the first option that was provided in the source material, ***Flashpoint #3 of 5 (2011)***. In the comic, Barry says he could basically unmake the suit, and at light speed change it. But says *screw that, it's easier to make a new one*.

[image]

[image]

In the movie adaptation, he vibrates it at super-speeds, changing it. Movie Allen is less lazy it seems. His line when he changes the suit implies the unweaving:

> I had to at least make some last-minute ***alterations***.

Unweaving, Alterations, it's a sewing joke.

<sub>*Since it's the Speed Force, you can just ignore any of that nagging physic side effects of moving matter at light speeds and the energy requirements and everything.* **He just can.**</sub>

Overall, the movie is a pretty straight, true to source, adaptation, almost scene to scene, line by line, with a few changes for action.